# Accessibly check on dynamic XFA form

Tags: forms, dynamic, xfa

We're maintaining a legacy application written in jsf 1.2 for the federal government. The application has downloadable pdf sections of dynamic pdf XFA templates. These templates were developed in adobe designer live cycle. States users download/fill these forms for their needs and submit to their states websites. As per government regulations these forms should be accessible (section 508 compliant). Can you tell me is it possible to convert these forms to accessible pdfs?